# how to select multiple date in calendar? how to change the back color of selected date?

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I have calendar in asp .net.my questions: how to select multiple date in calendar? how to change the back color of selected date? Can anybody have solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar1_PreRender function

refer following links

http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/03/09/tiptrick-aspnet-calendar-control-with-multiple-date-selections.aspx

http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2011/09/how-to-programmatically-select-multiple.html

Answer (score 0):

[See both Answers here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddates.aspx)

To Change back color of selected date

```
calendarToDisplayWorkSiteDates.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```